# Error when trying to use labelEncoder() in sklearn "Attribute error: module object has no attribute labelEncoder"

Tags: python-2.7, scikit-learn, attributeerror

I am new to python and sklearn. I installed sklearn using

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

This installed version 0.18.1 of scikit-learn. I verified that python is using the same version (sklearn.**version**)
However I get the following error
"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'labelEncoder'"
when I try to do the following:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.labelEncoder()
```

(I am using Python 2.7 if that is relevant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
```